# How to categorize rows and count uniques in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a table of data that has a state and city column.  I have sorted the table based on the two columns appropriately, however I am actually looking to just count the number of rows per each state and then another by cities for statistical analysis.

How do I count the unique entries in those columns and then display them in another portion of the table or in another table in the spreadsheet document?  I am assuming that doing this programmatically may be best.

Comment: Interesting, I've only used pivot tables in the past for other scenarios, but I've not used Excel very much over the past 10 years to be honest.

Comment: Give it a try and if you get stuck post back ;)

Comment: +1 for the pivot table option

Comment: I really liked that answer that had been added but was quickly deleted as it showed a programatic way to handle this it appeared.  Can we have that back?

Comment: @SiddharthRout how do you sort based on "Grand Total" column resultant from the process when using count of a column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say that a PivotTable does the trick. After about 3 minutes of playing around it became rather clear, although I have to say that the MS Office 2011 release I'm on is not very intuitive with regards to where to actually go.

Notwithstanding, I really liked @enderland's recommendation.  True it was not the solution exactly, but I usually prefer programatic approaches for solutions.  Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

> How do I count the unique entries in those columns and then display them in another portion of the table or in another table in
>   the spreadsheet document? I am assuming that doing this
>   programmatically may be best.

Something like this will be perfect

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A2:A10,A2:A10)>0,1))
```

This formula will give the result you are looking for. You may wish to change it to

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A:A,A:A)>0,1))
```

And it will summarize the entire A column without requiring a range.

---

I've undeleted this answer after your request, however, I am unsure it will do exactly what you are looking for as the first 1/2 of your question seemingly conflicts with the second half.